# converting xml-schema ref

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm refering to the element book and trying to convert this:

```
<xsd:element name="book" type="bookType"/>
<xsd:complexType name="bookType">
    <xsd:sequence>
            ...
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

To this:

```
<xsd:element name="book">
    <xsd:complexType name="bookType">
        <xsd:sequence>
                ...
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

The first parses XMLs but the second one stops validation with the error: "unable to parse schema file".

Any ideas? The XML syntax checker (notepad++ plugin) says that there are no errors detected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Inlining" a type, i.e. nesting it under another schema component, would prohibit the use of its `name` attribute. The name attribute for complex types is reserved for when the type itself is first level under the xsd:schema element.

A "normal" tool should tell you something such "The 'name' attribute cannot be present", then tell you the line and column position where the offending text was found. There are many good tools that offer free evaluation; downloading each, one after another, and it'll still give you enough to learn about XSD faster, and on top of that, increase your exposure to what's out there. Just don't ask here, on SO, what a good tool might be :)...

Comment: So it's a rule "thing" and we must follow it... No known bypass I guess?

Comment: @user2692669, no, it is part of the language. It is either named (or "global", therefore referenceable), or "anonymous" (local, scoped to the containing component only). While some people asked me before why not allow named, just as with, say, programming variables scoped to a statement block, I would think the XSD is complicated already... why bother?

Comment: XSD.. schemas... it's a whole different world! Thank you schema-guru!